# How to improve our stats?

Tags: discussion

On the Area 51 page it show the [statistics on the Ebooks beta site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46400/ebooks)

As were are not public yet, the recommended values are probably not valid (5 users with 3000+ rep e.g.), but it is interesting to keep in mind.

I was specifically wondering about the values in the box on the middle right in the "Beta" tab.

```
committed users

221 users committed
56.6% signed up for beta
0% fulfilled commitment
```

What can I do to fulfil (my part of) the commitment and change the zero in something more positive?

Comment: No commitments will be fulfilled until after the private beta is done.  I do not know if they are fulfilled immediately upon completion of private beta though

Comment: @Chad - seem to be - my Area51 added 50 rep to my account explicitly "for fulfilling commitment on ebooks". That happened 19:50pm 2 days ago, which I think is around when public beta started

Answer (score 6):

The commitment is quoted as 10 questions or answers but according to this [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123288/did-the-requirements-for-fulfilling-beta-commitments-change) implies that it is less that stated and it is not well defined.

The commitment text you signed up to appears to be

> "I commit to participate actively in Community X for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten questions."

Answer (score 5):

Maybe trying to add more Q+A, even if we already know the answer ourselves or if they seem obvious at a first glance, but that can be potentially interesting also for "outsiders". This should attract more visitors from web searches, bringing more potential users, traffic and so on.

Comment: And sometimes it turns out that there is an even simpler way or a completely different approach. Everybody wins.

Comment: I think this is definitely a valid approach.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that one way to improve our stats would be by not alienating good contributor users via:

- Closing questions off-topic without waiting for META consensus that they are actually off-topic.
- Deleting them when there's no consensus they are offtopic

Example: [Why was this question closed as off-topic?](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic?noredirect=1#comment111_78)

Comment: Although I agree in principle not to alienate good contributions, there already is a built-in mechanism of requiring multiple votes before doing so by requiring multiple votes. Don't forget you **vote** to close (or delete), and not close (unless you're a moderator).

Comment: @Anthon - judging by the speed with which the post disappeared, it was likely deleted by a moderator (I don't even think we have any users with high enough rep to delete). And communities where people VTC willy nilly without regard to formally announced scope rules tend to be quite toxic. If one can't point to a FAQ/about or a meta post with unambigous community consensus as an off-topic reason, "off-topic" should not be used as VTC.